# Accidentally deleted /usr/sbin/apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, reinstall

When trying to repair a failed installation of apache2, I deleted  `usr/sbin/apache2` thinking a reinstall would replace it. It did not and I get the following error when trying to start apache2:

```
service: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found.
```

Answer (score 11):

`/usr/sbin/apache2` is provided by apache2-bin. apache2-bin is a dependency of the apache2 package, so apache2 will not work properly without it. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin   
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: A stronger way to reinstall apache2-bin is `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq apache2-bin`

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the package the file belongs to:

```
dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2
```

Now, let's say it's `apache2-bin`, so we run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2-bin
```

Afterwards, the file should be restored.